# filtrar tabla a partir de opciones seleccionadas en un listbox

Tags: excel, vba, macros, filtro, listbox

Tengo un listbox que tiene como opciones diferentes paises, y necesito que al seleccionar 1 o mas paises de ese listbox me aplique el filtro de esas selecciones en una tabla.

la tabla la tengo en la hoja 4 y la columna 7 es la correspondiente a ciudades.
lo que necesito es que, si yo selecciono, Argentina, Argelia y Angola, me aplique dicho filtro en la tabla que tengo en mi hoja4

```
Private Sub GenerarInforme_Click()

Dim elementoLista As Long
Dim arreglo As Variant

With ListBox1
            
    For elementoLista = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(elementoLista) Then
            If ListBox1.Selected(elementoLista) = True Then
            seleccionados = seleccionados + 1
            End If
            
               Dim ary(1 To seleccionados) As String
                
            If seleccionados = 1 Then coma = "" Else coma = ","
            arreglo = arreglo & .List(elementoLista) & vbCrLf
            
            ary(seleccionados) = arreglo
        End If
    Next elementoLista
End With

If Len(arreglo) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No hay elementos seleccionados"
End If

Hoja4.Range("rango").AutoFilter _
 Field:=7, _
 Criteria1:=Array(ary), _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Este es el código que estoy utilizando pero siempre me filtra en blanco, es decir, no me selecciona ningún país.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Sub GenerarInforme_Click()

Dim elementoLista As Long
Dim arreglo As Variant

With ListBox1

    For elementoLista = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(elementoLista) Then
            If .Selected(elementoLista) = True Then
            seleccionados = seleccionados + 1
            End If
            
            Dim ary(1 To 500) As String
            
            arreglo = .List(elementoLista)
            ary(seleccionados) = arreglo
        End If
    Next elementoLista
End With

If Len(arreglo) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No hay elementos seleccionados"
End If
   
Hoja4.Range("BASE").AutoFilter _
 Field:=7, _
 Criteria1:=Array(ary), _
 Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

cambié esta linea

```
Dim ary(1 To seleccionados) As String
```

por esta

```
Dim ary(1 To 100) As String
```

y esta linea

```
arreglo = arreglo & .List(elementoLista) & vbCrLf
```

por esta otra

```
arreglo = .List(elementoLista)
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás utilizando el bloque `With Listbox` y dentro vuelves a hacer referencia, además compruebas 2 veces si el item está seleccionado. Por último, puedes utilizar un array para filtrar directamente, no necesitas hacer esos arreglos.

A ver si este código te ayuda:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub GenerarInforme_Click()

    Dim Filtro(1 To 1) As Variant: Filtro = ListaFiltros(ListBox1)
    If (Not Not Filtro) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No hay elementos seleccionados"
        End
    End If
    With Hoja4
        .Range("Rango").AutoFilter 7, Filtro, xlFilterValues
    End With

End Sub
Private Function ListaFiltros(formulario As ListBox) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To formulario.ListaHabilidades.ListCount - 1
        If formulario.ListaHabilidades.Selected(i) Then
            ListaFiltros = formulario.ListaHabilidades.List(i)
            ReDim Preserve ListaFiltros(1 To UBound(ListaFiltros) + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve ListaFiltros(1 To UBound(ListaFiltros) - 1)
    
End Function
```

Comment: Gracias @Damian  por tu respuesta, cuando la ejecuto me aparece un error "**no se puede asignar a una matriz**", en GenerarInforme_Click,  ¿que podrá ser?